# Как правильно создать вложенный expandable список?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Имеется следующая структура данных:

```
public class Main{
    List<Organisation> organisations;
}

public class Organisation {
    List<Group> groups;
}
public class Group {
    List<Person> persons;
}

public class Person {
    String name;
    String phone;
}
```

Задача сделать из этого список который выглядел бы так. Организации и группы сворачиваются. [image: К]

Пытался с помощью RecyclerView, создав отдельные holder'ы для организации, группы и персоны. 
Проблемы возникли при написании логики:

1. Как зная позицию элемента, узнать что это за элемент(Организация,
   группа или персона).(Начал велосипедить алгоритм который в цикле
   считает, но потом подумал, что это бред)
2. Как всё это дело коллапсить? Ведь если свернуть, кол-во элементов уменьшается, и на позиции, где раньше была персона, может быть группа или организация.

Comment: проще воспользоваться одной из [готовых библиотек](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=expandable+recyclerview+android&type=). если хочется самому, то можно изучить код этих библиотек для собственного решения

Comment: Я смотрел библиотеки, возможно не все, но те что я видел предлагали 1 либо 2 уровня вложенности, одна предлагала 3, но при условии одинаковой разметки для всех.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал следующим образом. Дал нужным классами общего родителя, в котором храню тип, состояние раскрытия и видимость:

```
public class Main{
    List<Element> elements;
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(elements);
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public class Element {
    Element(itemType){
        type = viewType;
    }
    int type;
    boolean isVisible;
    boolean isExpanded;
}

public class Organisation extends Element {
    Orgranisation(){
        super(0);
    }
    List<Group> groups;
}
public class Group extends Element {
    Group(){
        super(1);
    }
    List<Person> persons;
}

public class Person extends Element {
    Person(){
        super(2);
    }
    String name;
    String phone;
}
```

Если элемент не видим, делаем GONE. onBindViewHolder:

```
    if(element.isVisible) {
        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
    else {
        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
    }
```

Для каждого типа View создаю отдельный holder:

```
@Override
public ApplyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder = null;
    switch (viewType){
        case 0:
            holder = new OrganisationHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_organisation, parent, false));
            break;
        case 1:
            holder = new GroupHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_group, parent, false));
            break;
        case 2:
            holder = new PersonHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_person, parent, false));
            break;
    }
    return holder;
}
```

Пример логики сворачивания при item.onClick:

```
organisationView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                Organisation organisation = (Organisation) elements.get(getAdapterPosition());
                organisation.isExpanded = !organisation.isExpanded;
                for(Group group : organisation.groups) {
                    group.isVisible = organisation.isExpanded;
                    for(Person person: group.persons)
                        person.isVisible = group.isVisible && group.isExpanded;
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            });
```

Критика максимально приветствуется. Что не нравится лично мне: вместо Gone лучше бы удалять элементы из списка, тогда recycler сможет самостоятельно это всё анимировать. Но логика добавления элементов обратно в dataSet при раскрытии получается очень некрасивой.

Залил решение в репозиторий:
https://github.com/FirstSpectr/CollapseRecycler